# Camera image size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am writing a Cocoa application for mac osx. I'm trying to figure out how to determine the size of an image that will be captured by a camera? I would like to know the size of the image that will be captured so I can setup a view with an aspect ratio that won't distort the image. For example, if my view is defined to be 640x360 and my camera captures images that are 640x480, the displayed image looks short and fat. I'm also displaying some other layers over the image and I need the image size to be able to scale and position the layers properly.

I won't know the type of camera that is attached until run-time so I'd like to be able to interrogate the device and get attributes like image size. Thanks for the help...

Comment: Are you getting the pictures via IKPictureTaker, or some other method?

Comment: I'm using either the integrated camera in my MacBook or an external USB camera. The internal camera gives me an image that 1280x720 and the external camera is 640x480. The size of the image captured seems to be an inherent property of the camera being used. I just need to know, before capturing, what the size of the image is going to be so I can manipulate the size of the view I'm using to display it.

Comment: @Steve Oliver: You didn't answer his question. What API or library are you using to do the capture?

Answer (score 0):

You are altering the aspect ratio of the image when you capture in 640x360 instead of 640x480 or 320x240. You are doing something similar as a resize, using the whole image and making it a different size.

If you don't want to distort the image, but use only a portion of it you need to do a **crop**. Some hardware support cropping, others don't and you have to do it in software. Cropping is using only portions of the original image. In your case, you would discard the bottom 120 lines.

Example (from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_%28image%29)):

[image: crop example]

The blue rectangle is the natural, or original image and the red is a crop of it.